# Data from serial port comes in a vertical format

Tags: python

I've a python script that is reading from a serial port (TXRX) using a barcode scanner, everything works well, but my issue when text comes in from the serial port comes in a vertical format, something like this:

if the barcode that I am reading has 123456, it comes in my python script as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I've tried changing the print() options, but seems not have any luck.

```
import sys
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",115200,timeout=0.8)

print('serial test start ...')
if ser != None:
  print('serial ready...')
else:
  print('serial not ready')
  sys.exit()

ser.timerout=0.8 #read time out
ser.writeTimeout = 0.8 #write time out.

try:
  x = ""
  while True:
    t = ser.read()
    if t != b'':
      ser.write(t)
      x = x + t
      print(str(x)) #<--this one shows what it reads,line by line.

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  #print(str(x)) #<--this work fine when I I terminate the loop.
  if ser != None:
    ser.close()
```

I would like the text that I am capturing to look like:

```
123456
```

After updating my code, if I add the:

```
try:
  x = ""
  while True:
    t = ser.read()
    if t != b'':
      ser.write(t)
      x = x + t
      print(str(x))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  if ser != None:
    ser.close()
print(str(x))
```

I get this result: (I am reading is X001PB45ZF from a barcode)

```
X
X0
X00
X001
X001P
X001PB
X001PB4
X001PB45
X001PB45Z
X001PB45ZF
```

If I add it outside the loop:

```
try:
  x = ""
  while True:
    t = ser.read()
    if t != b'':
      ser.write(t)
      x = x + t

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print(str(x))
  if ser != None:
    ser.close()
```

I get this result, but only when I terminate the program.

```
X001PB45ZF
```

I added this to my code inside the loop:

```
try:
    while True:
         t = ser.read()
        if t != b'':
            ser.write(t)
            print(repr(t))
```

and the output now looks like this:

```
'X'
'0'
'0'
'1'
'P'
'B'
'4'
'5'
'Z'
'F'
'\r'
```

now that I see the `\r` at the end,  I can terminate my loop, right? and capture the text as needed? I am still trying to figure out how to terminate the loop when `\r` is giving by the scanner...

It worked now!!

```
try:
    x = ""
    # look for \r\n. if this doesn't work
    # try \x00
    while '\r' not in x:
        t = ser.read()
        if t != b'':
            ser.write(t)
            x = x + t
    x = x.strip() # removes whitepace from beginning and end of string
                  # including \r \n
    print(str(x)) 

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #print(str(x)) #<--this work fine when I I terminate the loop.
    if ser != None:
        ser.close()
```

Now that I can capture the input on a single line, how can I add it to an infinite loop?

My goal is to read the barcode, store it in a txt or DB. The barcode is in motion mode, meaning, as soon as the camera detects movement, the barcode will activate and try to read.

Comment: It looks like the strings read into t are terminated with carriage return line feed.  See if you can strip them off.

Comment: Why are you writing the received data back to the scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code is working as expected. `while True:` is an infinite loop. Usually you replace True with a condition you test for True.

The trick now is to figure out how to break out of your loop. What condition can we test for? Many barcode scanners will send a carriage return (\r = b"\x0d") or line feed (\n = b"\x0a") at the end of the message. Or some other character maybe.

You might have to dig out the manual for your barcode scanner and see if you can configure it to send a termination character.

Assuming you get '\r' at the end of transmission, you could modify while loop to become:

```
import sys
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",115200,timeout=0.8)

fid = open('output.txt', 'w')

print('serial test start ...')
if ser != None:
    print('serial ready...')
else:
    print('serial not ready')
    sys.exit()

ser.timerout=0.8 #read time out
ser.writeTimeout = 0.8 #write time out.

try:
    x = b""
    # look for \r\n. if this doesn't work
    # try \x00
    while b"\r" not in x:
        t = ser.read()
        if t != b'':
            ser.write(t)
            x = x + t
    x = x.strip() # removes whitepace from beginning and end of string
                  # including \r \n
    x = str(x)
    fid.write(x + '\n')  # write barcode to output file, one per line

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #print(str(x)) #<--this work fine when I I terminate the loop.
    fid.close()
    if ser != None:
        ser.close()
```

I've redone the indents in your code to 4 spaces per indent. Like you, I prefer 2 spaces. But the [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says 4 and sooner or later you may have to work with someone else and everyone else uses 4.

The code above should work once through. If you want to keep it running until a keyboard interrupt occurs, you need a second while loop.

```
import sys
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",115200,timeout=0.8)

fid = open('output.txt', 'w')

print('serial test start ...')
if ser != None:
    print('serial ready...')
else:
    print('serial not ready')
    sys.exit()

ser.timerout=0.8 #read time out
ser.writeTimeout = 0.8 #write time out.

try:
    x = b""
    # look for \r\n. if this doesn't work
    # try \x00
    while True:  # outer while loop. keeps writing barcodes to file until
                 # keyboard interrupt occurs
        while b"\r" not in x:
            t = ser.read()
            if t != b'':
                ser.write(t)
                x = x + t
        x = x.strip() # removes whitepace from beginning and end of string
                  # including \r \n
        x = str(x)
        fid.write(x + '\n')  # write barcode to output file, one per line

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    #print(str(x)) #<--this work fine when I I terminate the loop.
    fid.close()
    if ser != None:
        ser.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, @bfris, but still getting the same output... i would like to see X001PB45ZF in a single line, so that I can send the output somewhere else instead of the screen.

Comment: Hmmm. If you are still getting same output with the print statement OUTSIDE the loop, that implies you are getting some extra \r or \n. To debug, you can try to put `print(repr(t)) inside the loop to see if there are any extra unwanted characters. If there are unwanted characters, add `t = t.strip()` inside the loop.

Comment: I updated my post with more info, hope this clarify what I am doing and what I am getting.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think your code probably works fine, but you have to figure out how to break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: thanks @bfris... I added the ``` print(repr(t))``` I am seeing now the \r and ''... I have updated the main post with the new info...

Comment: @MrServer. Aha! You should be in good shape now. while loop becomes `while b"\r" not in x`, and it will successfully break out of the loop. Put the print statement OUTSIDE the loop, i.e. at the same indentation position as `while`, like I've done in my answer.

Comment: it worked!!! but had to put it INSIDE the loop, when I did it OUTSIDE wasn't getting anything at the screen, now that is inside, I can see the correct output and the loop terminates too. I've updated the post with the new changes. Now, how do I add all these to an infinite loop?

Comment: we are good now!! Thank you very much! your last piece of the code did it! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try not printing until after the while loop is finished.

```
try:
 x = ""
 while True:
   t = ser.read()
   if t != b'':
     ser.write(t)
     x = x + t
     #print(str(t))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print(str(x))
  if ser != None:
  ser.close()
```

Comment: tried and didn't make any change.  I used t.rstrip(), and also played with \r and \n, tried to add extra character to see if there was an extra line ( t.rstrip('88) ).. sees like nothing i did made a difference.

Comment: I see.  Instead of print inside the while loop can you append t to end of another string x?  And only print x after the interrupt has broken you out of the while loop.

Comment: it works if I print out after the look, since I am getting on this information from a barcode scanner, it will be difficult to terminate the loop. My goal is to capture the barcode and save it on a txt file or DB.     This is what I get when I print inside the loop                         
         `              
         X
         X0
         X00
         X001
         X001P
         X001PB
         X001PB4
         X001PB45
         X001PB45Z
         X001PB45ZF                                                      
         `

Comment: Can you update your post to show all of your code you are using now?

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to give you another solution.

Instead of printing, you can try to write on `stdout`.

Here is a snippet for you:

```
try:
  import sys
  while True:
    t = ser.read()
    if t != b'':
      ser.write(t)
      sys.stdout.write(str(t))
```

If this doesn't works, probably you are receiving a `'\n'` in your input.
You can use `str(t).replace('\n', '')` if that's the case.